# npm install connect issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to node.js. I have been undergoing Angular.js Pro by Adam Freeman

As per the installation step:

- I need to setup the web server for angular.js application using nodejs.
  Accordingly i installed node.js version 6.11.0 in the path:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

- Next step is to install connect module of nodejs using the command `npm install connect`.
  I am getting the below error message when doing so.
  [shell output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yejpw.png)

Can please anybody help with this.

Comment: Did you do `npm init`? This will generate a package.json file.

Comment: npm install will always try to install dependencies and libraries that are present in package.json , create a package.json file and retry again

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do that in the node.js path.
You can head over to a new directory say `~/desktop/temp`

And then first do `npm init`, which would set the project to use npm. It would ask a couple of questions.

Post this, do `npm install connect`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to start clean in an empty folder of your choice. This will be your project folder.

`cd` into it, then run `npm init`

Now you're ready to `npm install` whatever packages you need.